# Magento : getting error while passing data to controller function through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, magento, model-view-controller, controller

i am using magento and i am trying to post the form data to the controller action by using AJAX but i am getting this error :=>
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1/reliancedigital/index.php/crm/index/Registration/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

My ajax code is this :>

```
$j('#customerreg').on('click',function(){
                var value = $j('#email').val();
                $j.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl("crm/index/Registration")?>",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:$j('#registration').serialize(),
                    success:function(data){
                          console.log(data);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: Looks like you know what the problem is already `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing` either you can whitelist or pass the correct header or use a CORS override plugin for chrome for development https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because of server configuration. Contact your server team and inform regarding this error. They will defiantly resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs as your Magento site is not running on the same domain as your Ajax request url. You need to configure your Server to accept those calls by adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header.

Browser has cross-origin blocked you can not do any request to non host domain from javascript using ajax.

If you can't change server configuration then use JSONP requests.